# Variable is null, but right hand is not null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

While debugging I noticed something weird:

[image]

the result var is shown as null, both in mouse hover and in the watch, but the right hand side is actually returning non-null value as you can see in the watch.

Any ideas why?

**EDIT**: the result variable is also declared in the IF statement, something like this:

```
if (somethingIsTrue) { var result = xxx; }
else { var result = yyy; }
```

As soon as I renamed the second result to something else, all started showing correctly.

Comment: Clean and rebuild?

Comment: Maybe a case of multiple evaluation? First call gets null, puts it in result. Second call (to display it in the Watch) gets a value. What does `GetCachedData()` do?

Comment: actually in the main if block the result variable is also defined, so probably that's what's causing it.

if (something) { var result = xxx; } else { var result = yyy; }

as soon as I renamed it to something else in the Else block - all is shown properly.

Comment: Meh.  You are probably just running up against deferred execution.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/

Comment: @pbrian Not convinced the issue here could be deferred execution. Look at the watch, the right hand expression does return an object instance, not some IQueryable or something. It seems more like what mercer mentioned.

Comment: updated the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code is like this

```
if (somethingIsTrue) { var result = xxx; } else { var result = yyy; }
```

Then that 'result' variable is (re)declared within the scope of that if-statement. That means the value is only available within that block.

Solution: declare the variable outside of the block (if you haven't done that already) and remove the 'var's inside the 'if' and 'else' blocks